# Select statement with subquery to new table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm unable for the life of me to push results into a table. I'm fairly new to SQL and Snowflake so I'm sure that it's a simple syntax issue. The following code displays results just fine within Snowflake, but now I need to get these results into its own table called "Results" any help would be apprecaited!

Here is my working SQL Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."SOLAR"
WHERE "Home Phone" NOT IN(Select 'Phone' FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS")
AND "Zip" IN(Select "Zip" FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS");
```

Comment: The single quote of  `'Phone'` makes a string not select the `Phone` column from `CLIENTINPUTS` that would require a double quote to name the column.

Comment: Ironically the SQL statement I posted is the actual working SQL statement that generates 28k rows. When I change `'Phone'` to `"Phone"` it throws an error.

Comment: Understandable, if `phone` is not a column name it will not work. But if you are really  wanting to test if the "Home Phone" column value is not equal to 'Phone' string, then use `WHERE "Home Phone" <> 'Phone'` instead of `WHERE "Home Phone" NOT IN(Select 'Phone' FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS")` as they are doing the same thing presently..

Answer (score 1):

As suggested already you can use Create table "TABLE NAME" AS ... but "AS" keyword will come after the table name not before.

For example in your case;

```
CREATE TABLE RESULTS AS 
SELECT *
FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."SOLAR"
WHERE "Home Phone" NOT IN(Select 'Phone' FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS")
AND "Zip" IN(Select "Zip" FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS");
```

However in your code the sub-query has Phone defined as string 'Phone' it should have been either Phone or "Phone". In SQL ' ' is treated as string and it will not be evaluated at run time.

Modifying your code with correct syntax;

```
CREATE TABLE RESULTS AS 
SELECT *
FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."SOLAR"
WHERE "Home Phone" NOT IN(Select "Phone" FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS")
AND "Zip" IN(Select "Zip" FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports [`create table as`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html).  So:

```
CREATE TABLE AS new_table
    SELECT *
    FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."SOLAR"
    WHERE "Home Phone" NOT IN (Select 'Phone' FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS") AND
         "Zip" IN (Select "Zip" FROM "CTDBGI"."PUBLIC"."CLIENTINPUTS");
```